# go-pg, UpdateNotZero does not update nullable fields by design, how to do?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-pg

I'm having hard time trying to understand how to nullish a model field using [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg) and `UpdateNotZero()`.

**Example:**

```golang
type Player struct {
  ID            int
  CreatedAt     time.Time `pg:"default:now(),notnull"`
  UpdatedAt     time.Time
  AccountID     *int
}
```

Let's say I have this player now:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | created_at | updated_at | account_id |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2020-06-16 | NULL       |         12 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

in my GO code I need to "remove" `AccountID`, I need to nullish it: from `12` to `NULL`.

If I use `update()` like this:

```golang
...
player.AccountID = nil
_, err := db.Model(player).WherePK().Update()
```

it gives me the error:

```
ERROR #23502 null value in column \"created_at\" violates not-null constraint"
```

If I use `UpdateNotZero()` like this:

```golang
...
player.AccountID = nil
_, err := db.Model(player).WherePK().UpdateNotZero()
```

it doesn't update `AccountID` at all.

**How to do?**

---

Related issues I think:

- https://github.com/go-pg/pg/pull/1580
- https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/1557

Comment: Is the field unexported as presented in the question? Wouldn't such a field be ignored by go-pg? (genuine question as I'm not familiar with go-pg)

Comment: I updated the name, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the update to only the field you are trying to change:

```
_, err := db.Model(player).WherePK().Set("account_id = NULL").Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

UpdateNotZero() only updates fields that have values. Setting player.AccountID = nil means that you player.AccountID has no value. My closest guess is that go-pg parses nil as null, and so it does not update at all, because it go-pg sees the field as empty.